# With the hook entry_submission_end, is it possible to know if the entry is inserted or updated?

Tags: add-on-development, extension, hook

I'm working on an extension that indexes the content of the entry when publish form is submitted, but I need to know if the entry is a new one or an updated one, and in both case, I need the entry_id (the new one juste created or the old one).

Do you know a way to do that? Should I use an other hook?

--Solution--

In fact, entry_submission_end come with 3 parameters: entry_id, meta and data. If the entry is a new one, entry_id contains the new entry_id but $data['entry_id'] is 0, so you can have a condition on that to check if you are editing or creating an entry.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with that `$data` array...thank you for figuring this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually check if entry_id = 0 (for new entry)

```
$this->EE->input->get_post('entry_id') == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare `$meta['edit_date']` with `$meta['entry_date']`.

You will need to bring both dates to same format of course, as entry_date contains current timestamp, while edit_date is formatted as '%Y%m%d%H%i%s'

Comment: Hi Yuri, thanks, I thought about this solution but the entry date could be modified so it's not very safe.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for an answer here still then there is a simple test.

Along with the post data will be a value for entry_id, this is related to the originating entry id. So if this value is 0 then it is a new entry, if this value is > 0 then it is an update to an existing entry.

eg,

if ($_REQUEST['entry_id'] === 0) { // new post } else { // existing post }